# How can I read cursor object returned by find() query in python?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I connected the database with mongoClient from pymongo. I made a find() query but I can't read the result inside the cursor and I don't know why. Before I made this query from my local database and it worked, now I move all the code on a ubuntu server and the same code doesn't work anymore.

I tried this but it doesn't work on the server. On the local environment, it works

```
import json
import requests
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('mongodb://IP_ADDRESS/')
db=client.mydb
mycol = mydb["mycollection"]

array = []
for x in mycol.find():
    array.append(x)
print(array)
```

I also tried this but the response is a cursor and I don't know how to read this

```
import json
import requests
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('mongodb://IP_ADDRESS/')
db=client.mydb
mycol = mydb["mycollection"]

x = mycol.find()
print(x)
```

this is the output I obtained:

```
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x7fa7bd016c10>
```

my expected value is something like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d47f749fa8ca433e0d58b5f"), "value1" : "result1", "value2" : "result2", "value3" : "result3"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please find the below source code example.

```
for post in posts.find():
    print(post)
```

Comment: I already tried this solution. In the local environment, it works. But it doesn't work on the server for me!

Answer (score -1):

You will have to pass query and projections as per the MongoDB docs: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

try like this:

x = mycol.find(query, {"_id":1, "value1":1, "value2":1,...})
print(x)

1 basically means, which value you need to see in output.
If you want to see the value of key 'value1', then put it as "value1":1.
If you don't wish to see the value of key 'value1', then put it as "value1":0.

Comment: This have nothing to do with the projection. OP's scenario seems to concern with IP resolve issue, which causes the discrepancy between local and remote server.